# install ubuntu16.04 LTS on armv7l processor

Tags: system-installation

I want to install ubuntu 16.04 on armv7l processor, but I am unable to find any iso image of ubuntu for arm processor. Can someone help me with this

Comment: Is this AMD or Intel? They work well with Ubuntu.

Comment: I do not think that ARM is supported with Ubuntu. Thus, it has no ISO for it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm ?

Comment: @Edity I have installed Ubuntu in Beaglebone black (ARM processor).

Comment: @Edity AMD and Intel are both x86-based processors- this is the architecture they run on. However, ARM processors, such as Qualcomm Snapdragons, Exynos CPUs, etc., use a different type of architecture, called ARM. And yes, Ubuntu does have some support for ARM.

Comment: May I ask what device you want to install Ubuntu on?

Answer (score 1):

"Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS includes support for the very latest ARM-based server systems powered by certified 64-bit processors."

- [Ubuntu for ARM](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm)